# Using Jensen's inequality to prove the Cauchy distribution has no mean

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

I can see that there is no mean because  $\int x / \pi(1+x^{2})$ does not converge from -inf to inf. But my prof hinted at using Jensen's inequality for the proof.

$$f(E(X)) \le E(f(X))$$

How can I use this? We have not learned Cauchy principal value, so that is not applicable.

Comment: Well, you need to try identify some convex function in there ...

Comment: Well, $1/(pi(1+x^{2}))$ is concave, and $x/(pi(1+x^{2}))$ varies according to the interval.

Comment: @Bob: $\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ is concave in a neighbourhood of the origin, but it must have an inflection point since its limit when $|x|\to +\infty$ is zero.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't see how Jensen's inequality helps me here.